# React/JS/TS - Table won't render rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to simplify this one page and so I have a new component `Table.tsx` which does what it seems to do, render the head and rows of a table! HOWEVER, the rows aren't rendering in this case and it's tripping me out. Could it be me calling return for the rows a little before for `coinss` or `sparkline` to be defined?

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

import numabbr from 'numabbr';
import truncFixed from '../../../utils/truncFixed';

import DynamicTable from '@atlaskit/dynamic-table';
import Button, { ButtonGroup } from '@atlaskit/button';

import { Sparklines, SparklinesCurve } from 'react-sparklines';

import StarIcon from '@atlaskit/icon/glyph/star';
import EditorPanelIcon from '@atlaskit/icon/glyph/editor/panel';


export default function Table() {
  let [coinData, setCoinData] = React.useState<any>('');

  const fetchCoinData = useCallback(() => {
    axios({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d%2C14d%2C30d%2C1y",
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setCoinData(res.data)
      console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCoinData()
  }, [fetchCoinData])

  const createHead = (withWidth: boolean) => {
    return {
      cells: [
        {
          key: 'fav',
          content: 'Rank',
          width: 2,
        },
        {
          key: 'symbol',
          width: 5,
        },
        {
          key: 'name',
          content: 'Name',
          isSortable: true,
          width: 18,
        },
        {
          key: 'price',
          content: 'Price',
          isSortable: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  };

  const head = createHead(true);

  if ((typeof coinData.data !== "undefined") 
           && coinData.data !== null) {

    var coins = coinData.data;

    for(let i = 0, l = coins.length; i < l; i++) {
      var rows = coins.map((coin: any) => {
        let coinss = coin.sparkline_in_7d.price
        // return every 4 results in the sparkline
        // to make it less exact and more cute
        console.log(coinss)

        let sparklineee = coinss.filter((element: any, index: number) => {
          return index % 4 === 0;
        })
        return {
          cells: [                
            {
              key: 'fav',
              content: (
                <p>{coin.market_cap_rank}</p>
              ),
            },
            {
              key: 'symbol',
              content: (
                <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <p><b>{coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}</b></p>
                </span>
              ),
            },
            {
              key: 'name',
              content: (
                <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <p style={{ fontSize: 12}}>{coin.name}</p>
                </span>
              ),
            },
            {
              key: 'price',
              content: (
                <p>$<b>{truncFixed(Number(coin.current_price), 2)}</b></p>
              ),
            },
          ],
        };
      })
    }
  };   
  return (
    <DynamicTable
        head={head}
        rows={rows}
        rowsPerPage={100}
        defaultPage={1}
        defaultSortKey="mcap"
        defaultSortOrder="DESC"
        loadingSpinnerSize="large"
    />  
  );
}
```

EDIT: I mean.. `console.log(coinss)` doesn't even get called. Fairly confused, let me try to rewrite this in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using state.

`let [rows, setRows] = useState(null);`

Once your rows data is ready. Call `setRows(rows)` so that your component
knows to update. Currently your rows data is set after your component is rendered.

Use the following logic. (I had remove the util function since I didn't have it. You can add it and run.)

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import DynamicTable from "@atlaskit/dynamic-table";

export default function Table() {

let [rows, setRows] = React.useState<any>({});
let [loading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

let fetchCoinData = () => {
    axios({
        method: "GET",
        url:
            "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d%2C14d%2C30d%2C1y"
    })
        .then(res => {
            if (typeof res.data !== "undefined" && res.data !== null) {
                // Sliced Data - Fast
                let coins = res.data.slice(0,10);

                // Full Data - Slow
                // let coins = res.data;
                for (let i = 0, l = coins.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var rowsData = coins.map((coin: any) => {
                        let coinss = coin.sparkline_in_7d.price;

                        let sparklineee = coinss.filter((element: any, index: number) => {
                            return index % 4 === 0;
                        });

                        return {
                            cells: [
                                {
                                    key: "fav",
                                    content: <p>{coin.market_cap_rank}</p>
                                },
                                {
                                    key: "symbol",
                                    content: (
                                        <span style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                                            <p>
                                                <b>{coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </span>
                                    )
                                },
                                {
                                    key: "name",
                                    content: (
                                        <span style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                                            <p style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{coin.name}</p>
                                        </span>
                                    )
                                },
                                {
                                    key: "price",
                                    content: (
                                        <p>
                                            $<b>{coin.current_price}</b>
                                        </p>
                                    )
                                }
                            ]
                        };
                    });
                    setRows(rowsData);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchCoinData();
}, []);

const createHead = (withWidth: boolean) => {
    return {
        cells: [
            {
                key: "fav",
                content: "Rank",
                width: 2
            },
            {
                key: "symbol",
                width: 5
            },
            {
                key: "name",
                content: "Name",
                isSortable: true,
                width: 18
            },
            {
                key: "price",
                content: "Price",
                isSortable: true
            }
        ]
    };
};

const head = createHead(true);

return (
    <DynamicTable
        head={head}
        rows={rows}
        rowsPerPage={20}
        defaultPage={1}
        isLoading={loading}
        defaultSortKey="price"
        defaultSortOrder="DESC"
        loadingSpinnerSize="large"
    />
);
}
```

Comment: ah, good ol typescript trippin me up https://imgur.com/fPR058K.png also https://imgur.com/1vOWThx.png :/

Comment: Hey I updated the answer with a sample code. Can you try running it and see if it works this time. The error was occuring previously since there were two rows defined.

Comment: Awesome, yeah that works and looks amazing! Hey, is it just me or does the page freeze and take a while to load? Is there a way to go around that? :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It is building too many times or something else is wrong. Let me refactor the code. I will let you know when i update the answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying to find the best practices to apply throughout the entire app!

Comment: So you will need to implement pagination. And the useEffect was being called infinitely so that is fixed now. I have a line commented out. You will be able to see the performance difference. Also added a loading state to show a spinner until the API call is finished

Comment: Yeah that does help me out a lot. I've determined that using graphql to query the API and display the data on the client is somewhat faster and clearer